# How to count characters inside a NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a `NSString` like this

@"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,"

I want to count how many numbers are there in this string. How can I do that.
pls help me
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *numberString = @"1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
NSArray *numberArray = [numberString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSInteger count = numberArray.count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to get Number count in your string as below.

```
NSString *str = @"1,2,3,5,6,7,3";
    BOOL valid;

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        char chr = [str characterAtIndex:i];

        NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , chr];

        NSCharacterSet *alphaNums = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
        NSCharacterSet *inStringSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string];

        valid = [alphaNums isSupersetOfSet:inStringSet];

        if (!valid)
        {

        }
        else{
            count ++;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"=%d",count);
```

**Your Output is :**

[image]